# What's the maximum Job history size of Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

What's the maximum size of the job history in Google BigQuery?
Is there a limit for the amount of past jobs I can see?

If there is a limit, is there a way to list all the history through some API request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a limit to the job history in BigQuery. At some point, we might delete jobs after 90 or 180 days, but currently, job history is kept indefinitely.

You can list the job history via the [jobs.list()](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/list) api, which will return jobs in reverse order. You can use provided paging mechanisms to page through the results.